# stubbing in dummy data to http post during dev

Tags: angular

I have a method to get data from an endpoint

```js
  getManufacturers(): Observable<Manufacturers> {
    const requestBody = { 'num': 12 };

    return this.http.post<Manufacturers>(manufacturersUrl, requestBody).pipe(
      catchError(this.httpErrorService.handleError<Manufacturers>(`getManufacturers`))
    );
   }
```

The endpoint isnt ready.  I'd like to stub in dummy data, like:

```js
if(manufacturersUrl === 'dummy-data') {
  return dummyData
}
```

Two questions -- 1. what do I wrap that data in? A `BehaviorSubject.asObserver`? 2. is there a less destructive way to do this? Ie, can I change the result without changing the code in some more elegant way?

Comment: You can take a look at this: (http://jasonwatmore.com/post/2018/06/22/angular-6-mock-backend-example-for-backendless-development ). It takes advantage of Angular Interceptors to create a fake backend endpoint that could then be used to return your dummy data. I think that there is actually something else in Angular built to do basically the same thing, but I cannot find a reference to it and have never used it myself.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you simply return data

```
if(manufacturersUrl === 'dummy-data') {
  return of(dummyData)
}
```

Comment: while the other answer strives to be much more complete, and is truly elegant, it also ultimately fails because it will not work for a POST. yours is the best remaining answer and in fact hte one I have gone with.

Answer (score 2):

Use angular's InMemoryWebApi. Add dummy data in an in-memory-data service.
The advantage of using this is you don't have to change much of your code once your actual API is ready (need to change just the URLs).

Import `HttpClientInMemoryWebApiModule` after the `HttpClientModule` in your app module so that it will itercept the HTTP requests.

```
@NgModule({
  imports:      [ 
    ...
    HttpClientModule,
    HttpClientInMemoryWebApiModule.forRoot(InMemoryDataService,
    {
      dataEncapsulation: false,
      passThruUnknownUrl: true
    }),
    ...
  ],
  ...
})
```

Your in-memory data service will be something like:

```
import { InMemoryDbService } from 'angular-in-memory-web-api';

export class InMemoryDataService implements InMemoryDbService {
  createDb() {
    const heroes = [
      { id: 11, name: 'Mr. Nice' },
      { id: 12, name: 'Narco' },
      { id: 13, name: 'Bombasto' },
      { id: 14, name: 'Celeritas' },
      { id: 15, name: 'Magneta' },
      { id: 16, name: 'RubberMan' },
      { id: 17, name: 'Dynama' },
      { id: 18, name: 'Dr IQ' },
      { id: 19, name: 'Magma' },
      { id: 20, name: 'Tornado' }
    ];
    return {heroes};
  }
}
```

And your requests will be like:

```
constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }

getHeroes() {
  return this.http.get('api/heroes') // you just need to change this URL, once your API is ready
}
```

See this example: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-in-memory-untested-incomplete-mdvl5h?file=src%2Fapp%2Fhero.service.ts

**Edit**

To debug your requests, add a `responseInterceptor` in your `InMemoryDataService` class.

```
  responseInterceptor(res: ResponseOptions, ri: RequestInfo) {
      console.log(`response`, res);
      console.log(`request`, ri)
      return res
  }
```

Check this link: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-in-memory-untested-incomplete-fixlad?file=src%2Fapp%2Fin-memory-data.service.ts

Comment: Im missing how the in memory db maps to the url for the endpoint

Comment: @robertotomás Each array in the `InMemoryDataService` under `createDb()` will represent a table from your backend API, to reach to a particular table you just have to use a url like: `'api/tableName'` Also note: In memory db provides all the the HTTP methods.

Comment: This is what I was trying to recall. Good Answer.

Comment: thank you xyz --' how can I debug this ? I am not seeing my http post respond at all now

Comment: in fact the linked to example, if you change the first call from a get to a post, it also stops working

Comment: @robertotomás Check the update in the answer. If you change `get()` to `post()` ofcourse it won't work if you have done appropriate changes in the service which does HTTP calls. And you send body in a post request.

Comment: "of course it won't work" -- why ? the whole point to to make it work with a post, to match the call I am really going to be making.

Comment: @robertotomás Did you check the new link, I have added a post method there. *I said it won't work because a post method accepts a `body`, a get doesn't.*

Comment: the first get call actually has a configuration object though.. when you change post to get, the signature changes and that options block becomes a request body. It _should_ work.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/192224/discussion-between-xyz-and-roberto-tomas).